# Project file structure

Tags: python, architecture, directory-structure

I am currently working on a Pygame project and would like to seek your advice on best practices for organizing my code, particularly when it comes to creating additional scripts. I find myself indecisive with where to place certain functionalities, such as handling grid lines and GUI components. For example I created my `Surface` in main file (where the game loop is) and then made a separate file named `grid.py` with this code:

```py
def draw_lines(screen: pg.Surface, scroll_x):
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    for line in range(MAX_COL):
        pg.draw.line(screen, "black", (line * TILE_SIZE - scroll_x, 0),
         (line * TILE_SIZE - scroll_x, HEIGHT))
    for line in range(MAX_ROW):
        pg.draw.line(screen, "black", (0, line * TILE_SIZE), (WIDTH, line * TILE_SIZE))
```

then am calling this function every time I iterate through the game loop. (I also need to import this function into my main file)

What I find out about this approach is that am creating many files with usually just a few functions and I wonder if there is some more efficient and elegant way to handle this things. Im open to any suggestions!

Comment: The question is opinion-based. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

The most "elegant" way would probably be a module:

```
main.py
grid/
--__init__.py 
--some_submodule.py
```

To import them:

```py
import grid
grid.draw_lines()
grid.some_submodule.do_something()
```

Consider your codebase. Is it open source? Ask your contributors! Do people use it? Ask the users! There is no single answer to this question, but modules provide a reusable and organized way of doing it.

Comment: Yea, basically what I use rn and maybe I'll stick to it if I don't find something else. After all many files with less code ≠ wrong project structure. Thanks for the opinion tho!